# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character re

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the first two number of str "21N"

```
import re
str = "21N"
number = re.find(r\'d{1,2}', str)
```

but get this error, how do I get the first two number from the  the str
I'am very think for

Answer (score 0):

Move the backslash between the apostrophe and `d`:

```
number = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}', str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors. `re.find` doesn't exist, you can use `re.search` instead. And your backslash needs to be inside rather than outside your opening quote.

So the following would work:

```
number = re.search(r'\d{1,2}', str)
```

But the `{1,2}` is actually unnecessary if you know you're looking for exactly 2 digits. Just use:

```
number = re.search(r'\d{2}', str)
```

And as an aside, don't use the variable name `str`, as it is a built-in type in Python.